# Word VBA to find sentences containing two specific words

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to extract sentences containing the words "as" and "as", like the following:

He was as strong as a tiger.

But not:

He was an ass and a sajou.

I tried the following, but without success:
.Find.Text = "[ ][ ]*[ ][ ]"
.Find.Text = "  *  "

Also, I don't want the "*" to spread beyond a full stop. I don't know how to make the "*" means anything except a "."

Also, the fact that the word "as" is repeated twice is not relevant, as I would like to use the solution for other couple of words, example "father" and "son".

My code is:

```
Sub FindWordCopySentenceToSecondDocumentWITH_WILCARDS()
' the current document
    Dim aRange As Range: Set aRange = ActiveDocument.Range
' the new document
    Dim NewDocument As Document: Set NewDocument = Documents.Add
    Dim docRng As Range: Set docRng = NewDocument.Range

    With aRange
        .Find.Text = "[ ]<as>[ ]*[ ]<as>[ ]"
        .Find.ClearFormatting
        .Find.MatchAllWordForms = False
        .Find.MatchSoundsLike = False
        .Find.MatchFuzzy = False
        .Find.MatchWildcards = True
  
        Do While .Find.Execute
            aRange.Expand Unit:=wdSentence
            docRng.Characters.Last.FormattedText = aRange.FormattedText
            docRng.InsertParagraphAfter
            aRange.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
            
        Loop
    End With
    Set aRange = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: As an alternate idea, you could load in the VBScript.RegExp Object, and then loop through each sentence as a string. With Regex, you could check if each sentence matches a pattern `" as [^.]+ as "`

Comment: Refine your find text using the Word UI before you try to put it in code. For details of how to use wildcards see https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/General/UsingWildcards.htm